# array animation working on iPhone5 not iPad Air Xcode

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation

I have an amination that works on an iPhone but when I converted the project over to an iPad it doesn't show up or play.

```
containerArray14 = [NSArray array];
    containerArray14 =[[NSArray alloc ]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon2.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon4.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon5.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon6.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon7.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon8.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon9.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon10.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"moon11.png"],nil];

    stop2.animationImages = containerArray14;
    stop2.animationDuration = 2.0;
    stop2.animationRepeatCount = FLT_MAX;
    [stop2 startAnimating];
```

this is the code I use in viewDidLoad and it works great on the iPhone but nothing on the iPad.

if I make the uiimageview (stop2) just a still image it loads fine.  On the phone I have 10 of these going at the same time.  On the iPad I can't get even one to work.

Any ideas

Comment: I assume your duplicate declaration of containerArray14 is a typo ?

Comment: Also I think you set a repeat count of 0 and that will run infinitely.

Comment: Which is also the default value

Comment: The problem may be an x64 related with the FLT_MAX

Comment: Also perhaps where you've placed stop2 ? Is this on the screen ?

Comment: I implemented these ideas with no change. I have created stop2 in the .h file and then linked it in the storyboard and the above code is in  ViewDidLoad.  Like I said it works great in iPhone but not iPad.

Comment: I created a xib file instead of a storyboard view. linked everything and now everything is working great so I don't know must have been something when I brought it over from the iPhone xib file.  Anyway thx for all your input.